# como fazer uma consulta mysql que contem vários id separado por virgula

Tags: php, mysql

boa tarde, como posso fazer uma consulta onde eu tenho no meu campo `idProduto` varios `ids` de produto separados por virgula e listar cada um do seu respectivo.
exemplo: no meu `idProduto` eu tenho os `ids 1,2,6` quero que na minha consulta ele me retorne com o `inner join` os dados dos respectivos produtos que contem esses `ids` como posso fazer isso?

```
"SELECT p.id, p.idProduto, p.total, p.rastreio, p.envio, p.qtd, p.status, p.data, c.nome AS nomeCliente, c.email, c.telefone, c.cpf, c.cep, c.nResidencial, prod.nome FROM pedidos p INNER JOIN clientes c ON p.id_cliente = c.id INNER JOIN produtos prod ON prod.id = p.idProduto WHERE p.id = '$idPedido' "
```

Comment: Como esta o conteúdo dessa variável `$idPedido`?

Comment: intao esse conteudo seria para pegar o id do respectivo pedido por exemplo digamos que o `id` do pedido seja 1 ai ele vai me retornar somente os dados desse respectivo `id`, e dentro desse pedido com o `id=1` eu tenho varios produtos comprados. portanto esse `$idPedido` e mais pra saber os dados do respectivo pedido selecionado

Comment: Já tentou usar `WHERE p.id IN ('$idPedido')` ao invés de somente `WHERE p.id = '$idPedido'`  ?

Comment: Mas em caso de mais de um id como essa variável fica? (1,2,3,4,5) ?

Comment: nao so vai existi 1 id nessa variável o que vai existir mais que um id e no idProduto

Comment: acho que vocês tao intendendo errado eu já tenho o `$idPedido` esta correto o que eu quero e listar os produtos que estão no campo `idProduto` por exemplo eu coloquei no select prod.nome que eu quero o nome de cada produto que contem o `id = idProduto` ai no exemplo eu tenho o `idProduto` com 3 `ids` 1,2,6 intao ele me mostra 3 nomes que estao no `id 1,2,6` da tabela `produto`

Comment: Seu tu coloca `SELECT p.id, p.idProduto, p.total, p.rastreio, p.envio, p.qtd, p.status, p.data, c.nome AS nomeCliente, c.email, c.telefone, c.cpf, c.cep, c.nResidencial, prod.nome FROM pedidos p INNER JOIN clientes c ON p.id_cliente = c.id INNER JOIN produtos prod ON prod.id = p.idProduto WHERE p.id = '3'` funciona?

Comment: se eu colocar no `p.id` que e o id do pedido ele vai me retornar todos os dados onde o `p.id = 3` ate ai blz so que eu quero q ele retorne todos os nomes do `prod.nome`

Comment: ele so me retorna o primeiro nome e como eu tenho 3 `ids` ele teria que me retornar os 3 nomes. ex: `p.idProduto` contem os seguintes `id 1,2,3` blz quando eu faco o `inner join` `prod.id = p.idProduto` eu falo que cada id do `produto` tem que ser igual ao que está na minha coluna `idProduto` ou seja ele vai procurar pelos seguintes `ids` na tabela `produto` `1,2,3` e me trazer os nomes que estao nesses `ids` porem ele me traz somente o primeiro nome eu quero que ele me retorne 3 nome o nome do `id = 1`, o do `id = 2`, e o do `id = 3`, nao somente o do `id = 1`

Comment: `INNER JOIN produtos prod ON prod.id IN (p.idProduto)`
A instrução acima poderia dar certo já que os valores do `p.idProduto` estão separados por virgula, mas como ele retorna uma string ele lê o número até a primeira virgula retornando apenas um resultado. O que eu faria seria 2 consultas uma relacionando o pedido com o cliente dai vc teria então os pedidos, utilizando o PHP injetaria em uma outra instrução SQL fazendo o SELECT na tabela dos produtos os id's utilizando o `WHERE id IN ()`.

Comment: eu tentei fazer armazenei o `idProduto` em uma variavel e fiz a seguinte consulta `SELECT nome FROM produto WHERE id IN($listadeProduto)` porem ele me trouxe somente o primeiro resultado novamente, ele nao percorreu meus id ele pego so o primeiro novamente

Comment: Faz o seguinte, pega o resultado com os id's dos produtos e da um explode: `$idProdutos = explode(',',$idProdutos);`
Agora vc transformou a string em um array, cada id agora está separado, agora basta vc dentro dos parênteses do `IN` concatenar e fazer um foreach:
`(. foreach($idProdutos as $idProduto): echo $idProduto","; endforeach;.)`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode user a função find_in_set do mysql, sua query ficaria assim:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.idProduto,
    p.total,
    p.rastreio,
    p.envio,
    p.qtd,
    p.status,
    p.data,
    c.nome AS nomeCliente,
    c.email,
    c.telefone,
    c.cpf,
    c.cep,
    c.nResidencial,
    prod.nome
FROM
    pedidos p
INNER JOIN clientes c ON p.id_cliente = c.id
INNER JOIN produtos prod ON FIND_IN_SET(prod.id,p.idProduto)
WHERE
    p.id = '$idPedido';
```

e caso queira retornar os resultados em apenas uma linha, com os nomes dos produtos separados por ',' ou qualquer outro delimitador, pode usar a função GROUP_CONCAT e agrupar o resultado por pedido, que ficaria assim:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.idProduto,
    p.total,
    p.rastreio,
    p.envio,
    p.qtd,
    p. STATUS,
    p. DATA,
    c.nome AS nomeCliente,
    c.email,
    c.telefone,
    c.cpf,
    c.cep,
    c.nResidencial,
    GROUP_CONCAT(prod.nome SEPARATOR ',') AS nome 
FROM
    pedidos p
INNER JOIN clientes c ON p.id_cliente = c.id
INNER JOIN produtos prod ON FIND_IN_SET(prod.id,p.idProduto)
WHERE
    p.id = '$idPedido'
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Se passar a query string com aspas duplas como ali embaixo você consegue jogar direto a variável como ali em baixo.

Aí é só usar a cláusula IN, mas tem que garantir que os dados vem separados por vírgulas sempre.

```
"SELECT p.id, 
       p.idProduto, 
       p.total, 
       p.rastreio, 
       p.envio, 
       p.qtd, 
       p.status, 
       p.data, 
       c.nome AS nomeCliente, 
       c.email, 
       c.telefone, 
       c.cpf, 
       c.cep, 
       c.nResidencial, 
       prod.nome 
FROM pedidos p 
INNER JOIN clientes c 
    ON p.id_cliente = c.id 
INNER JOIN produtos prod 
    ON prod.id = p.idProduto 
WHERE p.id IN ($idPedido)"
```